# two level authentication error in config file

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, forms-authentication, windows-authentication

Trying to implement two level authentication with forms and windows into my application from the example at http://mvolo.com/iis-70-twolevel-authentication-with-forms-authentication-and-windows-authentication/.

when I add mikes code into my web.config file I get the error:

```
Line 27:   <location path="~/login.aspx">
Line 28:     <!-- Disable Forms Authentication -->
Line 29:     **<formsAuthenticationWrapper enabled="false" />**
Line 30:     <system.webServer>
Line 31:       <security>
Parser Error Message: Unrecognized configuration section formsAuthenticationWrapper.
```

does anyone have any idea as to why?

**EDIT**

Yes I have added his config section config

```
<section name="formsAuthenticationWrapper" type="Mvolo.Modules.FormsAuthConfigurationSection" />
```

but I dont think that is correct. should my type be different?> mikes website is `http://mvolo.com/` and his type is `Mvolo.Modules.`

Forgive me if this is a simple mistake still learning? what do I change the type to?

Comment: Do you also add the config section configuration the article tells you to add?

Comment: please see edit of Q. ta

Comment: If your FormsAuthConfigurationSection class is in the same project, under a different namespace, put the namespace you have. If it's in another assembly, you need to fully specify the assembly as well.

Comment: iv done a search in my project for FormsAuthConfigurationSection. its came up with no results. where can I find the location of this file? is it created by default on project creation?

Comment: The code or more than likely in the linked application for the article that you can download.